# Implementing a three-way join relationship in JPA 2.0

Tags: jpa-2.0, entity-relationship, join

I am trying to implement a **three-way join relationship** in JPA 2.0 (using annotations).

My domain is as follows:
[image: domain diagram]

I had a look at the `@JoinTable` annotation and I am not sure how to use it in order to implement the relationship.

Can anyone please provide clues or code samples?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question well, you actually have another `Entity`, let's call it `AdvertisementAssignment`. Then, this entity should have `OneToOne` association with each of your 3-way counterparts.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "ADV_ASSIGNMENTS")
public class AdvertisementAssignment {

    private Advertisement advertisement;
    private TimeSlot timeSlot;
    private Day day;

    // other properties definition (e.g. id, assigner etc.)

    // define constructor

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    public Advertisement getAdvertisement() {
        return this.advertisement;
    }

    public void setAdvertisement(Advertisement advertisement) {
        this.advertisement = advertisement;
    }

    // same for 'timeSlot' and 'day' properties
}
```